# Best car for the Tsukuba race from 08/01/2012 Japanese 80's Festival Seasonal Event?

Tags: gran-turismo-5

In the Seasonal event from August 1st, 2012, what is the best car to use in the 5 lap Tsukuba race (the first one). The event is a 420PP, 80's Japanese car race with comfort soft tires, and it's 5 laps. The lead car is usually 25-30 seconds ahead of you by the end of the first lap and I've never been able to get any closer than maybe 12 seconds from the first place car. The track is so short that it's difficult to see where to make up 3-4 seconds a lap when I'm already doing 1:08-09's.

Is there a car that makes this race easier? Were there any special modifications needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I used the Mugen Motul Civic to win it first time round. I took advantage of the fully customizable transmission to improve the low end acceleration and basically shorten all the gears (i don't see the point in long gears to achieve a theoretical top speed I don't have enough track to reach). I had the performance set to PP420. Since I have used the MR-2 G-Limited Supercharged at PP392 to win, as I prefer the MR style for cornering, but it's less forgiving than the civic.

More importantly though, as I discovered by being frustrated on the London event... the opponents make a huge difference. I tried London 10+ times coming only as close as 3/10 of a second from first, I exited the race came back in with a different lead car (city turbo) and won by 9 seconds. it seems certain cars despite the apparent pp ratings are way faster. The city turbo is the worst it seems, the mx-5's are beatable, but the gts-t skyline and the eunos roadster, i can't beat at all. I've never struggled to get second place, so I figure the only car you need to worry about is who is leading.

Comment: Just as a note, the real key here was to wait for the city turbo to be the car that starts in the lead.